# How can I add to my list from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, list

My app will receive SMS, save it in SQLite and then display it in my list.
The rest is done, but I can't get the data into my list; how can I do this?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                int position, long index) {
            // here send Recent case Object  OR or Recent case info.  to show case information

        }
    });
```

here is my adapter :

```
 public class RecentCaseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private RecentCases myPage;
static public List<RecentCaseClass> listOfCases;

RecentCaseClass entry;


public RecentCaseListAdapter(RecentCases R, List<RecentCaseClass> listOfCaseParameter) {
    this.myPage = R;
    this.listOfCases = listOfCaseParameter;

}

public int getCount() {
    return listOfCases.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listOfCases.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

     entry = listOfCases.get(position);

     if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myPage.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_cases_row, null);
      }

    // this is row items..
    // Set the onClick Listener on this button

    TextView tvCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvrecentName);
    tvCase.setText(entry.getName());
    TextView tvCaseInfo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recent_info);
    tvCaseInfo.setText(entry.getAge());

    // To be a clickable button



    return convertView;
}



public void add(RecentCaseClass rCaseClass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listOfCases.add(rCaseClass);
}


}
```

and here is my list

```
    public static List<RecentCaseClass> RecentCaseList = new ArrayList<RecentCaseClass>();

public static List<RecentCaseClass> getRecentCaseList() {
    return RecentCaseList;
}

public static void setRecentCaseList(List<RecentCaseClass> recentCaseList) {
    RecentCaseList = recentCaseList;
}
```

HERE WHERE I SHOULD ADD TO LIST

```
if (SMSReceived.startsWith("Hi")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Iam in hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            msg = SMSReceived;

            RecentCaseClass rCase = run();
            dbAdapter.add(rCase);

            All_Static.RecentCaseList.add(recent1);
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to understand how to get data from a SQLite table into a ListView?  It's not clear to me what aspect you're having trouble with.  Have you tried to use a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: You need to use an Adaptor inorder to  bind your data with the ListView.

Comment: @happydave please can you check my update

Comment: @ShashankKadne can you please check my Edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure what you're asking, so I don't know if this helps.  I think you want to roughly do the following:

1) Create a an android.database.Cursor object by querying for the data that you want to put in the list
2) Create a string array with the columns from the query that you want to display.  E.g. `String[] from_list = new String[] { "title", "case" }`

3) Create an int array with the ids of the TextViews in the list row that you want to fill in.  E.g. `int[] to_list = new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.case}`

4) Create a SimpleCursorAdapter to map the cursor to your list:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, R.layout.list_row, mCursor, from_list, to_list);
```

5) `setListAdapter(mAdapter);

Is this at all helpful?

Comment: NO, i did all the DB and adapter and bla bla,but now i have baseadapter for my list and cursor for my DB, the problem is : How can i show the user the information inside baseadapter, can you please check my code?? i did it all, i think my probelm is really small line but i can not get it